# Remove undefined elements from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a table where I pull data and add it to an array of arrays. The problems is if one of the table cells is empty it appears in the array as "undefined". I tried using an if the last element is undefined if so using .pop() the element should be removed. I still get undefined elements. Here's my code and live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Tqxz/5/)

**HTML :**

```
<table id="contactlisttable">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="contactlist contactlistlastfirst">Joey</td>
        <td class="contactlist contactlisttitle">webdesigner</td>
        <td class="contactlist contactlistphone"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="contactlist contactlistlastfirst">Anthony</td>
        <td class="contactlist contactlisttitle">webdesigner</td>
        <td class="contactlist contactlistphone">5555555</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**JavaScript :**

```
//IE9+ compatable solution
$(function(){
    var results = [], row; 
    $('#contactlisttable').find('th, td').each(function(){
        if(!this.previousElementSibling){ //New Row?
            row = []; 
            results.push(row); 
            if($(this) === 'undefined'){//Remove undefined elements
                row.pop();
            }
        }
        row.push(this.textContent || this.innerText); //Add the values (textContent is standard while innerText is not)       
    }); 
    console.log(results); 
});
```

---

Comment: What would you like to go in the array is the field is undefined?

Comment: This would also remove the "sparse" aspect of the array. Why not just use an object at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/8rW4q/)***

Instead of doing the conditional statements, just take advantage of your html structure. First select by the table rows, and then iterate the child `td` or `th` elements. You can also take advantage of jQuery's `text` instead of doing the feature detection. jQuery's text will be more reliable.

```
var results = [];
$('#contactlisttable tr').each(function(){
 var row = [];
 $(this).find('td,th').each(function(){
     row.push($(this).text());
 });
 results.push(row);
});
console.log(results);
```

Comment: +1 An inner loop makes far more sense. Could use `.map()` to create the Arrays too, though you'd need to work around jQuery's auto-flattening for the inner `.map()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing and popping if it doesn't match, don't push in the first place.

Updated from your jsfiddle:

```
//IE9+ compatable solution
$(function(){
    var results = [], row; 
    $('#contactlisttable').find('th, td').each(function(){
        if(!this.previousElementSibling && typeof(this) != 'undefined'){ //New Row?
            row = []; 
            results.push(row); 
        }
        row.push(this.textContent || this.innerText); //Add the values (textContent is standard while innerText is not)       
    }); 
    console.log(results); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid adding undefined (or actually empty) elements this way:

```
$('#contactlisttable').find('th, td').each(function(){
    if(!this.previousElementSibling){ //New Row?
        row = [];
        results.push(row);
    }
    if(!(this.textContent == '')){
        row.push(this.textContent || this.innerText);            
    }
});
```

Comment: Travis J's answers is far more appropriate for this case.

Answer (score 0):

To know if something is undefined dont just compare to `"undefined"`, use typeof().

So you want to do :

```
if (typeof(this) === "undefined")
```

Comment: That will never be true because you are constructing a jQuery object. The object will never return undefined as its type. I didn't downvote though, just pointing it out.

Comment: Indeed, just whent too fast. Corrected.

Comment: `typeof` isn't a function. You don't neeed the parens.

Comment: It avoid bleeding eyes.

Comment: @EoiFirst do you do the same thing with `return`, i.e.: `return(true)`? Making non-function keywords look like function calls makes _my_ eyes bleed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a compact method like in underscore and lodash...

```
Array.prototype.compact = function() {
    return this.filter(function(x){
        return x !== undefined;
    });
}

console.log([1,2, '', undefined, 'e', undefined].compact()); // [ 1, 2, '', 'e' ]
```

You should probably add a check for a native implementation of `compact` as well, since you are overriding a native prototype with this.

Or, just

Comment: Why put `compact()` on `Function.prototype` if it's only meant to work with Arrays?

Comment: My bad, early morning :P... Updated.